# Multiprocessing pool запускает весь скрипт вместо одной функции

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

Я использую Spyder 5.0.3 с Python 3.7.9 (Windows 7) на одном компьютере и Spyder 5.2.9 с Python 3.7.9 (Windows 10) на другом.
На моём компьютере при использовании `multiprocessor.pool` всё работает как мне нужно (пример будет ниже). На другом, такое ощущение, что выполняется параллельно не одна функция, а весь скрипт.
Пример. Есть скрипт.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def example(num):
    return num**2

print('Hello')

n_proc = 4
numbers = [0,1,2,3]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = n_proc)
    print(pool.map(example,numbers))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

На моём компьютере вывод такой:

```
Hello
[0, 1, 4, 9]
```

На другом:

```
Hello
[0, 1, 4, 9]

Hello
Hello
Hello
```

Т.е., будто весь скрипт несколько раз запускается.
Для интереса попробовал запустить скрипт через командную строку напрямую без Spyder. На обоих компьютерах получил вывод:

```
Hello
[0, 1, 4, 9]

Hello
Hello
Hello
```

Таким образом, у меня три вопроса:
1). Правильно ли я понимаю, что второй вариант вывода всё-таки более правильный?
2). Почему при запуске скрипта через Spyder вывод отличается от того, что можно получается через командную строку?
3). Как малой кровью исправить проблему/переделать скрипт, причём так, чтобы это решение работало на как можно большем количестве компьютеров (Windows)? Я писал и отлаживал прогу на своём компе и работала она так как мне надо. Я не был готов к тому, что для каждого компа придётся переделывать скрипт)
Задача ещё осложняется тем, что перед записью самой функции, которая должна параллельно выполняться, у меня формируются исходные данные для неё. Может, есть уже какие-то готовые решения для такой задачи, которые я не знаю?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ну это же мультипроцессинг. Он запускает **процессы**. Т.е. да, как бы подгружается весь скрипт целиком в другой процесс, хотя из него и должна запуститься только одна функция. Попробуйте убрать всё кроме функции внутрь защитной проверки `if __name__ == "__main__":`, она нужна не только при выносе кода в библиотеки, на `windows` она нужна ещё и для того, чтобы в запущенных дополнительных процессах не запускался лишний код:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def example(num):
    return num**2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Hello')
    n_proc = 4
    numbers = [0,1,2,3]
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = n_proc)
    print(pool.map(example,numbers))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Я понял, что у вас где-то и без этого работает правильно, но если хотите, чтобы правильно работало везде - делайте как правильно.

**Update:** Пример передачи нескольких параметров в функцию:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def example(num, aleop):
    return num**2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Hello')
    n_proc = 4
    numbers = [0,1,2,3]
    aleops = [1,1,2,2]
    with mp.Pool(processes = n_proc) as pool:
        print(pool.starmap(example,zip(numbers,aleops)))
```

Comment: Вы привели пример здорового человека. И вот такой вариант решения проблемы я рассматриваю на крайний случай, если не найду лучше. Но в нём есть недостаток. Допустим, перед объявлением функции example, мне необходимо сформировать исходные данные. Получается, при распараллеливании у меня эти исходные данные будут формироваться для каждого процесса. Если я уберу их в защитный блок, то функция не сможет на них сослаться. Есть ли возможность правильно перед объявлением функции один раз подготовить для неё исходные данные, а далее при распараллеливании запретить выполнение блока перед функцией?

Comment: `Допустим, перед объявлением функции example, мне необходимо сформировать исходные данны` в ответе это и делается. `numbers = [...]` это и есть подготовка данных. Вы можете там вызывать любые функции опеределнные на верхнем уровне. Главное не делайте эту подготовку за пределами блока if. Если вы хотети сослаться на глобальные данные (т.е. не на что-то, что вы передаете в паратметрах в `example`, то каждый процес должен будет эти данные создать сам. Чтоб это делалось один раз - нужно передавать параметром в `example` из главного процесса.

Answer (score 0):

@Roman Konoval, @CrazyElf, я имею ввиду такой вариант:
Допустим, я хочу перед объявлением функции задать степень в которую возвожу уже в самой функции. Типа такого:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

#Блок кода, определяющий степень (переменная aleop) для функции example

def example(num):
    return num**aleop

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Hello')
    n_proc = 4
    numbers = [0,1,2,3]
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = n_proc)
    print(pool.map(example,numbers))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Вот этот блок кода будет повторяться при выполнении каждого процесса, получается.
Если этот блок кода загнать в `if __name__ == "__main__":`, то компилятор, естественно, ругается на отсутствие переменной aleop.
Для примера выше повторение не критично, но у меня изначально большой скрипт с большим количеством исходных данных, формируемых для выполнения функции, которую надо распараллелить.

Comment: Я добавил в свой ответ пример передачи двух аргументов в функцию. Заодно переделал на `with` создание пула, так правильнее.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).